# Convert date format comes from database using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, frontend

I need to change my date format comes from database,for that I have seen many solutions but I need certain solution. here given my date
**2015-08-15 02:54:43**
I need to change this date into **Aug-8 02:54 AM**.
Please, provide me the certain solution
Thank you

Comment: The ideal solution should be doing the date format in the SQL query rather than doing it in the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use date.js here below I have given an example

first of all include following both js in your page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js"></script>
```

then
write following script bottom of the page

```
<script>
    var date = '2015-08-15 02:54:43' //your date
    var parseDate = Date.parse(date);
    alert(parseDate.toString("MMM-d hh:mm tt"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can format `Date` in SQL query also, but if there is situation where you have to format in jquery then you can use:

## [Moment](http://momentjs.com/)

> Its a plugin, to Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in
>   JavaScript.

Instance:

```
$(function(){
    var divLocal = $('#divLocal');  
    var localTime  = moment("2015-08-15 02:54:43").toDate();
    localTime = moment(localTime).format('MMMM-DD h:mm:ss A');//August-15 2:54:43 AM
    //localTime = moment(localTime).format('MMMM-MM h:mm: A');//output August-08 2:54:43 AM
    divLocal.text(localTime);     
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lasn8zq0/)